# std::string::insert doesn't work with to_string(). CPP

Tags: c++

I am writing a code to insert an integer at an index of the string, but after providing the integer to add as string, insert function is not giving the correct output.

It is giving the error that :

> no matching member function to call for insert string

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()  
{
    string s = "45564528";
    int x = 8;
    s.insert(s.begin()+5,to_string(x));
    cout<<s<<endl;
   
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is 455648528.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert is adding a char std::to_string is returning a string https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string you can do something like this: string foo = to_string(x);
s.insert(s.begin()+5,foo.begin(),foo.end());

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi thank you. I got the syntax now.

Comment: there are a lot of way to do it, this might even better s.insert(5,foo); basic_string& insert( size_type index, const basic_string& str );

Comment: @ThomasSablik as said in the question I was trying to add an integer to a string by converting the integer to a string using the to_string() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) for `std::string::insert()` shows that it takes a `char` or an iterator range, not a `std::string`, which `std::to_string()` naturally returns. At least, this is the case for the overloads that take an iterator for the first argument.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  // CHANGED: Include what you use

// using namespace std;  // CHANGED: Bad practice

int main()
{
    std::string s = "45564528";
    int x = 8;

    // CHANGED: Create string from the int, and use the iterator range overload
    // to account for multi-digit numbers
    auto tmp = std::to_string(x);
    s.insert(s.begin()+5, tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
    std::cout << s << '\n';  // CHANGED: std::endl is rarely actually needed

    return 0;
}
```

There is an overload that lets you insert another `std::string`, but the first argument must be an index and not an iterator. So this would work as well:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "45564528";
    int x = 8;

    s.insert(5, std::to_string(x));
    std::cout << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't like "using namespace std", but it is really consider bad practise in the header. https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-using so, in this specific instance it is fine

Comment: I consider it a bad practice generally.